# Is it possible to train a binary classification SVM model with my particular dataset and have it predict accurately?

Tags: classification, svm, supervised-learning

I have a dataset of about 19 000 records.  I am training my SVM with 10 features and want to have it do binary classification.  My current predicament is that all my predictions are currently coming out as `false`.  I kind of understand why, but would just like to know what the best way is to move forward and whether I have any chance of my model being successful.

Only roughly 7% of my total dataset has an actual `true` label, which is about 800 records.  Is it correct that I then need to train against about 80% of those and a similar number of records with a `false` label?  If I do so, does my model have any chance of predicting the remaining 16 000 records correctly?

In short, does my dataset lend itself to machine learning at all?  Does it lend itself to machine learning but not the SVM model in particular?  Or do I just need to curate my training data and features and tweak my model and that should give my a respectable accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try an [oversampling technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis) for your training data. Anyway, unbalanced dataset is a major issue concerning classification problems, so don't expect any miracles.

I would also try different models (logistic regresssion, trees...) and check which one deals best with the unbalance